# Why isn't this snippet + Zoo Triggers working?

Tags: stash, snippets, zoo-triggers

I have a set of "category" pages such as:

- Dining (example.com/dining)
- Nightlife (example.com/nightlife)

We are using Zoo Triggers to filter out the categories appropriately. I am using a snippet to insert an icon into the header of each category. This snippet looks like so:

```
{exp:stash:set name="logo"} 
    {snippet:masthead_logo}
{/exp:stash:set}
```

The "logo" snippet looks much like this:

```
<div class="logo">
{exp:ifelse parse="inward"}
{if segment_1=='events'}
    <img src="{site_url}images/placeholders/icon-events.png" height="125" width="125"/>
{if:elseif triggers:segment_1=='dining'}
    <img src="{site_url}images/placeholders/icon-dining.png" height="125" width="125"/>
{if:elseif segment_1=='nightlife'}
    <img src="{site_url}images/placeholders/icon-nightlife.png" height="125" width="125"/>  
{if:elseif segment_1=='shopping'}
    <img src="{site_url}images/placeholders/icon-shopping.png" height="125" width="125"/>
{if:elseif segment_1=='arts-culture'}
    <img src="{site_url}images/placeholders/icon-arts.png" height="125" width="125"/>
{if:else}
    {exp:ce_img:pair src="{interior_logo}" max="125" crop="no|center,center" fallback_src="{site_url}images/placeholders/member-placeholder-logo.png" allow_scale_larger="yes"}
        <img src="{made}" alt="{title}" width="{width}" height="{height}" />
    {/exp:ce_img:pair}
{/if}
{/exp:ifelse}
</div>
```

As you can see I am testing "dining" for Zoo Triggers segment_1, which is 'dining' when it parses. However, the conditional is not holding true as it were. In fact, not even the surrounding  is passed from the snippet. So I suppose it isn't as much a why isn't this conditional working, but more of a why isn't this snippet working?

Comment: FYI: The icons DO in fact display when the URL is www.example.com/dining, but when it is www.example.com/dining/category/thai do we run into the issue of the empty stash.

Comment: Do you need to use the triggers segment if the dining images does not change between www.example.com/dining and www.example.com/dining/category/thai?

Comment: No, it was just a test. Drilling down. It seems anything inside the {exp:channel:entries disable="trackbacks|pagination" {triggers:entries}} tag does not stash properly.

Comment: Have you tried setting [`parse_conditionals="yes"`](https://github.com/croxton/Stash#parse_conditionals--yesno) on the `{exp:stash:set}` tag?

Comment: I had. It turns out to be user error of course! I had a misplaced tag, that killed everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tracked the issue down and it was an errantly placed {triggers:entries} tag. Completely my fault, but thankful that I had the answers I received to make me look long and hard at the template.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 2):

In your code above 'logo' is a Stash variable, not a snippet. You would need to access it like {exp:stash:get name="logo"}. You *could* add type="snippet" to the stash:set tag when you set the variable and then access it like so: {logo}; however I'm not sure why you don't just use the original snippet itself: {snippet:masthead_logo} ?

Comment: I updated the code a bit. {logo} should actually have been {interior_logo}. The stash:set is inside a channel:entries tag because in some instances a page requires a custom logo/icon, but for the most part they are as defined.

Comment: Ho hum. Figured it out. User error, of course. Thanks Mark.